# Ruby begin rescue end with if-then-else

Tags: ruby, function, rescue

I am kind of stuck with using begin-rescue-end with if-else-end. Please see the code snippet below.

```
def fn1
    unless fn2?
        puts "Message 1"
        return
    end

    puts "Message 2"
end

def fn2?
    begin
        <do action>
    rescue
        <handle error here>
        puts "Message 3"
        return
    end

    if <condition>
        puts "Message 4"
        return true
    else
        puts "Message 5"
        return false
    end
end
```

In the begin block, if there is no exception raised, then if-else will get executed and return true or false to fn1. No problem with this.

But in the begin block, should an exception be raised, I want to just print "Message 3" and end the program, without printing "Message 1".

Any pointers please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to terminate the program (instead of just returning from `fn2?`), you can use [Kernel#exit](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-exit), for example:

```
begin
    <do action>
rescue
    <handle error here>
    puts "Message 3"
    exit(1)
end
```